# Unwanted name column in DataGridView - How can I get rid of it?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm making a WinForms application using VB.NET. I have a DataGridView that I am using to display results of a query to an SQL-Server Database. This works fine:

```
Dim SQL As New SqlConnection()
Dim CMD As New SqlCommand()
Dim ADP As New SqlDataAdapter()
Dim TBL As New DataTable()

SQL.Close()
SQL.ConnectionString = "Server=" & GetServerIP() & ";Database=" & GetDB() & ";User Id=" & userID & ";Password=" & pass & ";"
CMD.Connection = SQL
CMD.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " & table

SQL.Open()

ADP.SelectCommand = CMD
TBL.Clear()
ADP.Fill(TBL)

DataGridView1.DataSource = TBL
```

The issue is that the DataGridView has a column NAME which is empty in every row. 
[image: Which looks like this]

I tried changing the query to `SELECT SEQ_NUM FROM CONFIG_SYS` that resulted in a DataGridView with a NAME and SEQ_NUM column. I tried calling `DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()` before the `DataGridView1.DataSource = TBL` and that does not have an effect on anything. I should mention that if I query any table in my database that does not have a NAME column, I get the same results with an empty NAME column in my DataGridView.

My theory is that a DataGridView automatically adds NAME as the first column, expecting the Database Table to be set up with a NAME column as the primary key. However, my table does not have NAME, it has a column called SEQ_NUM as the primary key. I am able to work around this by doing `DataGridView1.Columns("NAME").Visible = False` but I don't feel that this is the best way to do it.

Is there a better way to handle this - I'd like the column to not exist at all in the data grid, not just not be visible.

Comment: The name column either is coming from the query, or your grid has a column called NAME already there.

Comment: @LarsTech I already verified that the query does not return a name column. The DB Table does not even have a NAME column. And the DataGridView is never used until this instance - I don't understand how it could have any column already there at all.

Comment: Your situation isn't recreatable though.  Try doing this in a new project, see if the problem happens there.

Comment: As quick fix you could add `DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()` before the `DataGridView1.DataSource = TBL` statement.  But you should search your project to find where it is being added.  From the "Edit Menu->Find and Replace->Quick Find", search the entire solution for `DataGridView1.Columns.Add`.

Comment: Try to change your SQL Statement from `select * from table` to `select SEQ_NUM,ENTRY_CODE,VALUE... from table` to check if there is still a `Name` column.

Comment: @LarsTech I am able to recreate the situation every time. If my database table does not have a name field, I have a blank name column in my DataGridView.

Comment: @Code Pope I had already tried that before posting, I will add that to my question. It produces the same result.

Comment: @TnTinMn That did not get rid of the NAME column, and I never manually add any columns to the DataGridView. The DataGridView is completely empty and unused until my query runs and then the DataGridView gets set to my DataTable.

Comment: I'm sorry because I understand that it is not easy to test my code since it requires an SQL Server with a database and I don't expect anyone to create that in an attempt to help me out; but I promise that I have tried everything within my and Google's knowledge before making a post. I believe my "theory" that I stated in my question is true, but I can't find anything online to prove it.

Comment: If clearing the Columns collection did not work, then the "Name" column exists in `TBL` and since that DataTable is being filled filled by the query, the only source is the query that returns all fields in the connected DB.  Set a breakpoint and step through the code to ensure that all variables contain what you believe they do.

Comment: @TnTinMn Thank you so much. I've never made use of Visual Studio's breakpoints, but the more I learn about VS the more I love it. I was able to see exactly what every variable was, and VS had a custom viewer for the datatable, which is awesome. I've used breakpoints in other editors but they weren't nearly as useful so I kind of shrugged them off for VS as well, but I really shouldn't have. I figured out the problem and I will post it as an answer. Thank you to everyone who commented as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What was causing my issue was the fact that I was calling `TBL.Clear()` incorrectly.

Calling `DataTable.Clear()` will clear the Data from a DataTable but it will leave the columns in place.

Instead I should have been calling `TBL.Columns.Clear()`, which gets rid of the columns of the DataTable. However, using Breakpoints and Visual Studio's DataTable Visualizer I noticed that only calling `TBL.Columns.Clear()` left the empty rows still in the DataTable. Therefore, to answer the question of how to get rid of a column in a DataGridView that you don't know why/how is there, I suggest to call:

```
DataTable.Clear()
DataTable.Columns.Clear()
```

Before setting your DataGridView equal to your DataTable.

### Taken from the MSDN:

The [.Clear() Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.clear?view=netframework-4.7.2) of a [DataTable Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netframework-4.7.2) "clears the DataTable of all data."

The [DataTable.Columns Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.columns?view=netframework-4.7.2)  gets "a DataColumnCollection that contains the collection of DataColumn objects for the table"

The [DataColumnCollection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumncollection?view=netframework-4.7.2) also has a [.Clear()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumncollection.clear?view=netframework-4.7.2) Method which "clears the collection of any columns."

---

Thank you @TnTinMn for pointing me in the right direction by using breakpoints and @LarsTech for making me realize that I harshly mixed up DataGridView and DataTable in my original answer.

I hope this post can help others prevent themselves from ripping their hair out about where a non-existent column in their databases seemingly materialized from... If this does not fix your specific issue. I would also check the Query, Database Table setup, and the DataGridView; but for me the issue was with the DataTable.

Comment: `DataGridView.Clear()`  There is no such method.

Comment: @LarsTech What do you mean by "there is no such method?" If you read the explanation from MSDN the .Clear() Method belongs to the DataGridViewColumnCollection Class and can be used on a DataGridView Control. I am using it in my project without any error, and it works perfectly. I just did not understand that it only clears the data and not the columns. As per my answer, to clear the columns you must also call `DataGridView.Columns.Clear()`.

Comment: Do you have some kind of custom DataGridView or something?  `Dim dgv As New DataGridView()`  `dgv.Clear()`  will result in "Clear is not a member of ...DataGridView."

Comment: I see what you mean now. I butchered my answer. I was getting the DataGridView Control and DataTable Object mixed up. I will edit my answer to be correct. I apologize.